# sumar 2 números complejos

Tags: java

Necesito sumar 2 números complejos, ejemplo: Z1=5-3i , Z2=-4+2i
Necesito añadir un método que realice la operación y después, haces que el main utilice ese método para imprimir el resultado.
Este es mi avance:

```
package appcomplejo;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class AppComplejo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Complejo num1=new Complejo();
        num1.escribir_complejo();

        Complejo num2=new Complejo(5,7);
        num2.escribir_complejo();
        double re,im;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Parte real: ");
        re=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Parte imaginaria: ");
        im=sc.nextDouble();

        num1.definir_complejo(re, im);
        num1.escribir_complejo();
        System.out.println("Val abs: "+num1.absoluto(num1));


        System.out.print("Parte real: ");
        re=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Parte imaginaria: ");
        im=sc.nextDouble();

        num2.definir_complejo(re, im);
        num2.escribir_complejo();
        System.out.println("Val abs: "+num2.absoluto(num2));

                }

}
```

---

```
package appcomplejo;

public class Complejo {
    double real;
    double imag;

    Complejo() //Constructor
    {
        real=100;
        imag=100;
    }

    Complejo(double re,double im)
    {
        real=re;
        imag=im;
    }

    void definir_complejo(double re,double im)
    {
        real=re;
        imag=im;
    }

    void escribir_complejo()
    {
        System.out.println(real+"+"+imag+"i");
    }

    double absoluto(Complejo c)
    {
        double valorabsoluto;

        valorabsoluto=Math.sqrt(c.real*c.real+c.imag*c.imag);
        return valorabsoluto;
    }

}
```

Comment: Necesitas imprimir la suma de los dos números?

Comment: Exacto... no logro hacer el algoritmo para calcular la suma de 2 números complejos. ejemplo: Z1= 5-3i , Z2= -4+2i
necesito imprimir la suma eso, Gracias.

Comment: La suma de dos complejos no es igual a la suma de la parte real mas la imaginaria? Tenes que sobrecargar el operador suma, o que es lo que tenes que hacer?

Comment: Si, es eso... tengo que añadir un método que permita realizar la suma, y después hacer que el main utilice ese método.

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/211246/edit) tu pregunta agregando datos extra del problema

Comment: Ok, lo haré....

Comment: Un metodo en la clase? o solo un metodo?

Comment: un método en la clase.

Comment: si ya hiciste todo eso, no veo por qué no has podido, sólo sumas las partes reales y las imaginarias por separado

Answer (score 2):

Deberias implementar un metodo "suma" en tu clase Complejo que retorne un objeto de tipo Complejo tomando como parametro un objeto tipo Complejo... ufff

```
 public Complejo sumar(Complejo a){
    return new Complejo(this.real+a.real, this.imaginario+a.imaginario);
 }
```

No probe el codigo pero debe ser algo asi lo que estas buscando

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo hice.

Comment: Si este metodo esta dentro de la clase complejo.. es innecesario pasar 2 numeros, ya que uno deberia ser el de la clase ;)

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por la observacion, edito mi respuesta!! :D